# Function call problem in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have written a function `scroll()` in code my behind, and called it using `<% Response.Write(scroll()); %>` in ASPX page. Function is working properly but in Internet Explorer it shows Error on Page message at corner.

I also tried  `<%=scroll() %>` to call it, still showing error on page message.

Can anybody tell me another way to call function?

Plz help.

Thanks.

Comment: **1.** Write your function's declaration please. **2.** What do you mean by page message corner? **Info**: `<%= %>` is completely equivalent to `<% Response.Write(); %>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing some thing wrong, We can call server side function in code behind file like:

### Default.aspx

Form tag start
 Div start
  <%= Scroll() %>
 Div end
Form tag closed

### Default.aspx.cs

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
    }
    public string Scroll()
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

}

try it out its working and match it with your code.